# I keep getting a cannot find symbol error for a variable

Tags: java, methods

I think I am just calling my variable to my main the wrong way, I want to convert feet to meters and meters to feet and print out ten iterations, with feet starting at 1.0 and meters starting at 20.0 going to 10.0 and 65.0 respectively.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class FeetMeters
{
   public static void main(String [] Args)
  {



     System.out.println(" Feet   \t Meters \t | \t Meters \t Feet");
     System.out.println("________________________________________________________________");


     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

           System.out.println(foot + " \t " + meter + " \t " + " | " + "\t" + meter  + " \t " + foot);
           foot++;
           meter = meter + 5;
        } 
     double footStart = footToMeter(meter);
     double meterStart = meterToFoot(foot);   

  }

   public static double footToMeter(double foot)
  {
     double meter = 0.305 * foot;
     return meter;


  }

   public static double meterToFoot(double meter)
  {
     double foot = 3.279 * meter;
     return foot;


  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636815/cannot-find-symbol-compiler-error)

Comment: i know what the error is, i just need help fixing it.  i need to get the program to actually use the two formulas i have in the bottom two methods.  Again i think i am calling them to the main incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps you should be calling your methods in your loop? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the actual error message, which points to a specific variable, but you never declared `foot` or `meter` in your main method.

Comment: im sorry! it was pointing to foot and meter, but when i initialized them, and my program ran, it just printed foot and meter to the tenth iteration adding one and five, it never actually used the formula.

Comment: @Chrylis just wanted to say when I posted my answer I dawned on we are talking about the same issue, so just know did not mean to copy your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is **not defining** variables meter and foot

add following lines after main method signature

```
public class FeetMeters {
     public static void main(String [] Args)
         {   
          double foot = 0.0;
          double meter = 0.0;

          rest of your code
```